# Dynamic values in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

I have visual force page and apex class to display the list of contacts in a data table.
I am querying Name, Title Specialty in the controller.
Specialty field contains values such as Primary department, Secondary department, etc...
In the visual force page for an account record if the specialty is Primary department then it should display as PD in the UI and if it is secondary department should display as SD.
Basically, I don't want to hardcode the values in the controller.
Can someone provide examples how to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Use a formula...

Comment: I can't make it as a formula field

Comment: Use wrapper class with custom getter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hard code the value in apex class. My suggestion is store the value in custom setting use.
Next what you will do is that, modify you code in such a way, you will get Specialty field by query into contact. now check what is the short form value in custom setting for that Specialty field. Use wrapper class to store that short form of Specialty field and display in visualforce page.

Refer below code snippet. It may help you:

```
Map<String,custom_settings__c> custom_settings_object_map =new Map<String,custom_settings__c>();
custom_settings_object_map = custom_settings__c.getAll();

 for(String specialField : custom_settings_object_map.keySet()){
    if(custom_settings_object_map.get(specialField) == contactRecord.Speciality_field__c){
        String short_form = custom_settings_object_map.get(shortform);
        wrapperclass wr = new wrapperclass(parameter1,parameter2,.........,short_form);
    } 
 }
```

Make sure you will create custom setting properly